# WCF - Modify endpoint behavior configuration at runtime

Tags: .net, wcf, service-discovery, ws-discovery

I create WCF service with endpoint discovery behavior (WS Discovery). It is possible to modify discovery behavior (adding/removing scopes) at runtime or refresh service behaviors? 
I tried like this:

```
var serviceEndpoint = this._machineReporterServiceHost.Description.Endpoints.Find(typeof(IMachineReporter));
var endpointDiscoveryBehavior = serviceEndpoint.Behaviors.Find<EndpointDiscoveryBehavior>();
endpointDiscoveryBehavior.Scopes.Add(new Uri("uuid:7673868d-231e-490d-9c4f-19288e7e668d"));
```

scope has been added to endpoint behavioral object but the service has not been updated (client not found service).